# Can I upload App to App store developed in Xcode 10.1 and Swift 4.2

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store, ios11

Recently I developed an app and I want to submit it to the App store, but I developed this app on **Xcode 10.1** in which maximum support Swift version is **4.2** and deployment target in 12.1 
       now question I want to ask as Apple released **Xcode 10.2** with **Swift 5**. so can I upload this app to app store or it is necessary to develop this app in **Xcode 10.2**?

Comment: Try it. Does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple required iOS app to be built with iOS 12 SDK which comes with Xcode 10 ([reference](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09122018c)).
Apple now requires iOS app to be built with Xcode 10.1. ([reference](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/devb1c185036)).
So as long as you build your app with Xcode 10.1 or higher you will be fine for now.

Comment: that still applies ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you should use **Application Loader** or **AppUpLoader** to upload the build on appStore.

Comment: Irrelevant to the question.

Comment: You just need to create the build from your xCode 10.1 Having swift version 4.2 and push the build to app store via application loader. You need not to develop the app with xCode 10.2. Check this link - https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204456258-iOS-Uploading-Builds-Using-Application-Loader